# OpenCV Python align 4 corners of an element

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have the location of the 4 corners of the element but I want to straighten it
My image looks like this representation:

[From misaligned to aligned element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHJY0.png)

The said element is in an image so I'd like to apply the alignment to the whole image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are searching for is a homography Transformation.

First you need the positions of your  4 corner points of the image and then your have to define the destination of those 4 points. In your case it would be the image boundaries. If you have your destination points, you can call the function `H, mask = cv.findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints)`(see documentation in [calib3d module](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga4abc2ece9fab9398f2e560d53c8c9780)).

The matrix H describes the transformation from your source image to the destination image. Next you need to apply the Matrix H on your image which can be done with the function 
`dst = cv.warpPerspective(srcImage, destImage,H)` (see documentation of this function [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87)).

If you want to do more stuff with the homography matrix, see [OpenCv Homography tutorial with example code](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html)